# Why do all riders in the Tour wear WHITE bike shoes?

Tags: tour-de-france

The riders in the Tour de France all wear WHITE bicycle shoes. Why is everyone with white?   Is that a rule in the Tour?

Comment: Its about Fashion not function. Today its white, tomorrow who knows, pink?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's rather fashion or style related.

Comment: I agree with closing this. StackExchange sites in general focus on practical questions that can be answered. Opinion-based questions are a much better fit for Reddit. For example, /r/velo deals with competitive cycling, and I bet someone would render an opinion there. Alternatively, you could also try /r/bicycling.

Answer (score 12):

They don't. Here are some links to examples:

https://www.bikeradar.com/features/tour-de-france-shoes-gallery/
https://www.bikeradar.com/features/top-5-custom-road-shoes-at-the-tour-de-france/
https://cyclingtips.com/2019/07/photo-gallery-the-best-shoes-of-the-2019-tour-de-france/

You can see some blue ones, yellow ones, orange ones, black ones, purple ones, etc.

Comment: Long ones, tall ones, short ones, brown ones, black ones, round ones, big ones, crazy ones?

Comment: And probably the odd guy wearing two different ones. ;-)